# Magento 2 - add rule block above grid filter

Tags: magento-2.1

I have created a product grid and want to add a Rule block above grid content.

After so much research I found that function `getMassactionBlockHtml()` can be used to call Rule block.

But the function `getMassactionBlockHtml()` is not getting called in my case.

Below is my grid class with `getMassactionBlockHtml()` function

```
<?php
namespace Company\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Listproduct;

class Grid extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Extended
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Module\Manager
     */
    protected $moduleManager;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Entity\Attribute\Set\CollectionFactory]
     */
    protected $_setsFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory
     */
    protected $productFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type
     */
    protected $_type;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status
     */
    protected $_status;
    protected $_collectionFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility
     */
    protected $_visibility;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\WebsiteFactory
     */
    protected $_websiteFactory;

    protected $_template = 'Company_Module::grid.phtml';

    protected $showAdvancedFilterProductsOption = true;
    protected $useAdvancedFilter                = true;

    public $hideMassactionColumn                = false;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Backend\Helper\Data $backendHelper
     * @param \Magento\Store\Model\WebsiteFactory $websiteFactory
     * @param \Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Entity\Attribute\Set\CollectionFactory $setsFactory
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $productFactory
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type $type
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status $status
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility $visibility
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Module\Manager $moduleManager
     * @param array $data
     *
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveParameterList)
     */
    public function __construct(
        //\Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
         \Company\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Magento\Context\Template $context,
        \Magento\Backend\Helper\Data $backendHelper,
        \Magento\Store\Model\WebsiteFactory $websiteFactory,
        \Company\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Listproduct\Collection $collectionFactory,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $productFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Module\Manager $moduleManager,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type $type,
        array $data = []
    ) {

        $this->_collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
        $this->_websiteFactory = $websiteFactory;
        $this->moduleManager = $moduleManager;
        $this->productFactory = $productFactory;
        parent::__construct($context, $backendHelper, $data);
    }

    /**
     * @return void
     */
    public function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();

        $this->setId('productGrid');
        $this->setDefaultSort('id');
        $this->setDefaultDir('ASC');
        $this->setSaveParametersInSession(true);
        $this->setUseAjax(false);

    }

    /**
     * @return Store
     */
    protected function _getStore()
    {
        $storeId = (int)$this->getRequest()->getParam('store', 0);
        return $this->_storeManager->getStore($storeId);
    }

    /**
     * @return $this
     */
    protected function _prepareCollection()
    {

        parent::_prepareCollection();


        try{


            $collection = $this->productFactory->create()->getCollection()
                ->addAttributeToSelect('sku')
                ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
                ->addAttributeToSelect('type_id');

            $collection->joinTable(
                array('cisi' => 'cataloginventory_stock_item'),
                'product_id=entity_id',
                array(
                    'qty' => 'qty',
                    'is_in_stock' => 'is_in_stock'
                ),
                '{{table}}.stock_id=1',
                'left'
            );

            // ---------------------------------------
            $collection->getSelect()->distinct();
            // ---------------------------------------

            // Set filter store
            // ---------------------------------------
            $store = $this->_getStore();

            if ($store->getId()) {
                $collection->joinAttribute(
                    'price', 'catalog_product/price', 'entity_id', NULL, 'left', $store->getId()
                );
                $collection->joinAttribute(
                    'status', 'catalog_product/status', 'entity_id', NULL, 'inner',$store->getId()
                );
                $collection->joinAttribute(
                    'visibility', 'catalog_product/visibility', 'entity_id', NULL, 'inner',$store->getId()
                );
                $collection->joinAttribute(
                    'thumbnail', 'catalog_product/thumbnail', 'entity_id', NULL, 'left',$store->getId()
                );
            } else {
                $collection->addAttributeToSelect('price');
                $collection->addAttributeToSelect('status');
                $collection->addAttributeToSelect('visibility');
                $collection->addAttributeToSelect('thumbnail');
            }

            //echo $collection->getSelect()->__toString();



            $this->setCollection($collection);

            $this->getCollection()->addWebsiteNamesToResult();



            return $this;
        }
        catch(Exception $e)
        {
            echo $e->getMessage();die;
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column $column
     * @return $this
     */
    protected function _addColumnFilterToCollection($column)
    {
        if ($this->getCollection()) {
            if ($column->getId() == 'websites') {
                $this->getCollection()->joinField(
                    'websites',
                    'catalog_product_website',
                    'website_id',
                    'product_id=entity_id',
                    null,
                    'left'
                );
            }
        }
        return parent::_addColumnFilterToCollection($column);
    }

    /**
     * @return $this
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveMethodLength)
     */
    protected function _prepareColumns()
    {
        $this->addColumn(
            'entity_id',
            [
                'header' => __('entity_id'),
                'type' => 'number',
                'index' => 'entity_id',
                'header_css_class' => 'col-id',
                'column_css_class' => 'col-id'
            ]
        );
        $this->addColumn(
            'sku',
            [
                'header' => __('sku'),
                'index' => 'sku',
                'class' => 'sku'
            ]
        );

        $this->addColumn(
            'name',
            [
                'header' => __('name'),
                'index' => 'name',
                'class' => 'name'
            ]
        );



        $block = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('grid.bottom.links');
        if ($block) {
            $this->setChild('grid.bottom.links', $block);
        }

        return parent::_prepareColumns();
    }


    protected function _prepareMassaction()
    {
        $this->setMassactionIdField('entity_id');

        return parent::_prepareMassaction();
    }



    protected function getProductTypes()
    {
        $magentoProductTypes = $this->type->getOptionArray();
        $knownTypes = $this->getHelper('Magento\Product')->getOriginKnownTypes();

        foreach ($magentoProductTypes as $type => $magentoProductTypeLabel) {
            if (in_array($type, $knownTypes)) {
                continue;
            }

            unset($magentoProductTypes[$type]);
        }

        return $magentoProductTypes;
    }



    public function getMainButtonsHtml()
    {
        $html = parent::getMainButtonsHtml();
        $addButton = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Button')
            ->setData(array(
            'label'     => 'Show Advanced Filter',
            'onclick'   => 'ProductGridObj.advancedFilterToggle()',
            'class'   => 'task'
        ))->toHtml();
        return $addButton.$html;
    }


    protected function _toHtml()
    {
        $html = '';
        //$html = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('mymoudule/adminhtml_myblock')->toHtml() . '<br />';
        $html .= parent::_toHtml();

        return $html;
    }


    public function getMassactionBlockHtml()
    {


        /*if (!$this->useAdvancedFilter) {
            return $this->hideMassactionColumn ? '' :  parent::getMassactionBlockHtml();
        }*/

        $advancedFilterBlock = $this->createBlock('Listing\Product\Rule');
        $advancedFilterBlock->setShowHideProductsOption($this->showAdvancedFilterProductsOption);
        $advancedFilterBlock->setGridJsObjectName($this->getJsObjectName());

        return $advancedFilterBlock->toHtml() . (($this->hideMassactionColumn)
            ? '' :  parent::getMassactionBlockHtml());
    }





}
```

This is screenshot [image]

I want to show the rule block after click on "Show Advanced Filter"